# Ruby/Gem altering array for no apparent reason

Tags: ruby, arrays, rubygems

I have the following code:

```
comment_array = ['I.','He6']
comment_array_altered = []

  comment_array.each do |comment|
    comment_array_altered << comment
  end

  comment_array_altered.each do |x|
    emotion_array << Chime.emotion(x)
    polarity_array << Chime.category(x)
  end

puts comment_array
```

What the `Chime.emotion` and `Chime.category` are doing is pretty irrelative, but know that it is not accessing `comment_array` at all. It is only doing work on `x`, which is an object within the array `comment_array_altered`. This is what is happening when I do `puts comment_array`:

```
i
he
```

The original array is being altered to remove punctuation, integers, and it makes all words lowercase. Is there any explanation why this would be the case? For what it's worth, this is exactly what the Chime gem is doing (removing punctuation, integers, and making words lowercase) but the gem should not be operating on this array, only on `comment_array_altered`.

Comment: You should look into the source code of Chime gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
comment_array = ['I.','He6']
comment_array_altered = []

  comment_array.each do |comment|
    comment_array_altered << comment.dup
  end

  comment_array_altered.each do |x|
    emotion_array << Chime.emotion(x)
    polarity_array << Chime.category(x)
  end

puts comment_array
```

The Chime gem is probably doing stuff with the references you are passing to it, and you probably want an altered *copy* instead. That's what `dup` is for.

BTW, you can rewrite the code like this:

```
comment_array = ['I.', 'He6']
emotions_array = comment_array.map { |x| Chime.emotion(x.dup) }
polarity_array = comment_array.map { |x| Chime.category(x.dup) }
```

Comment: The Chime gem must be doing stuff with the references - Being new to Ruby I did not realize the difference between a reference and a copy of the reference, but the `.dup` makes sense. Thanks for the tip, and +1 for the rewrite. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to figure out what's happening:

```
comment_array = ['I.','He6']
comment_array_altered = []
comment_array.each do |comment|
  comment_array_altered << comment
end
```

At this point, `comment_array_altered` has been initialized and populated. The two arrays are different objects in memory:

```
comment_array.object_id # => 70148571674460
comment_array_altered.object_id # => 70148571820360
```

Here are the objects inside `comment_array`:

```
comment_array.map{ |o| o.object_id }
# => [
#     [0] 70148571674600,
#     [1] 70148571674540
# ]
```

And here are the objects inside `comment_array_altered`:

```
comment_array_altered.map{ |o| o.object_id }
# => [
#     [0] 70148571674600,
#     [1] 70148571674540
# ]
```

Notice that the elements are the same `object_id`.

As the other answers point out, using `dup` on the elements will duplicate them as new objects.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. These kind of troubleshooting tips are what I need to learn. Meanwhile, stackoverflow.com!

Comment: Knowing how to see what the object's ID is is a very useful thing for these sort of weirdnesses. I'm a very big believer in learning to use the debugger, which lets you see deep inside your code and variables. Everyone on our team gets a big dose of "what did you see in the debugger?" when they ask me why something doesn't work, whether it's Ruby, Perl or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

```
comment_array.each do |comment|
  comment_array_altered << comment
end
```

is pushing *references* into the new array. Making changes to those will alter the original data.

It seems that `emotion()` and `category()` are modifying the reference parameters that are being passed into them, which would cause this sort of thing to happen.

This should fix it:

```
comment_array.each do |comment|
  comment_array_altered << comment.dup
end
```